# IE 8 Error - What's the cause?

Tags: magento

I have two magento eshops that worked perfectly in the past on all major browsers except IE 7.
After I installed WINDOWS XP on my computer and accessed my eshops with IE 8, I almost had a heartattack seeing that they aren't working as they should. 
Before installing Windows XP I was running Windows 7 and the websites were looking good on IE 8. Now, the same IE version, but on different operating systems, gives me headaches!

Now, can someone explain me how to 'debug' the ie 8 parsing engine for seeing the errors and try to modify the templates?

Thanks.

Comment: @rekire I'd like to, but it's still an important browser used by many people worldwide.

Comment: @SteveRobbins Can you make some print screens please? Are you sure you accessed it with IE 8 ? A product page?